# How to debug "IndexError: string index out of range" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve Ex. 9.6 Think Python 3.

> Question: Write a function called is_abecedarian that returns True if the letters in a word appear in alphabetical order (double letters are ok). How many abecedarian words are there?

What I have written:

```
fin= open('words.txt')
for line in fin: 
line=fin.readline()
word=line.strip()
c=0
index=0
for letter in word:
    if ord(letter)<ord(word[index+1]):
        c=c+1
        index=index+1
if c==len(word):
    print(word)
```

My approach is to convert letters to numeric value and match them with the next letter in the word by increasing the index by 1 each time loop ends and count each time. If count comes to be equal to the length of word that means all the times the previous letter was lesser in value than next. So print the word.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\KARAN\Desktop\Python\Programs\practice.py", line 8, in <module> if ord(letter)<ord(word[index+1]): IndexError: string index out of range
```

I am getting 'IndexError' but I don't think index that is 0+1=1 should be out of range? I tried to search it up but couldn't get my answer.

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of the error. Don't leave us guessing as to where it might be raised and in what context.

Comment: Python indexing starts at 0 and ends at `len(sequence) - 1`. You are looping all the way up to `len(word)` here, so you'll get an index error for the last letter.

Comment: ah.. thanks Martijn, i didnt take care of that. Lemme try again with that

Comment: This is a simple lack of effort in debugging. You always look at the "next" letter, but how do you do that when you are on the last letter?

Comment: It seems to me that with this algorithm, you take a word of X characters and do X-1 comparisons. So, the word `an` has 2 letters and 1 comparison. You could modify your `for` loop to iterate between 0 and X-2, or you could modify your `if` statement.

Comment: I don't know Python, but maybe something like `if (index < len(sequence) - 1) and ord(letter)<ord(word[index+1])` might do it - I'd assume that if the first test fails then the second one won't run at all, and so won't cause an index error.

Comment: Finally you would need to modify your last test, since in an X letter word, you only want X - 1 increments to succeed on a word.

Comment: Thank you @halfer for the detailed answer. I appreciate that so much.

Comment: My solution have worked! @halfer but i would add the solution only if i knew how to add code in comments. Everything is being merged into one single line if i try to.

Comment: Select the block of code, and click the 'code' button in the toolbar. This puts a four-space indent in front of all selected lines, which is Markdown shorthand for code.

Comment: I have added the solution above in my question explanation. Here in comments everything was merging in a line so thats why.

Comment: Don't forget to test it with single-letter words - it looks like it should work.

Comment: I will keep that in mind always. Thank you for being so helpful friend.

Comment: Yea i just saw thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Final solution:

```
fin= open('words.txt')
for line in fin: 
    line=fin.readline()
    word=line.strip()
    c=0
    index=0
    while index!=(len(word)-1):
        i=(word[index])
        j=(word[index+1])
        index=index+1
        if ord(j)>=ord(i):
            c=c+1
    if c==(len(word)-1):
        print(word)
```

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that you would also need to do `fin.close()` to make sure you are not leaking anything. a simple `with open('words.txt) as fin:` block would handle that for you.